# How to call hook before and after in ember-qunit tests?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I have to exec some code before all tests began. So I need to use QUnit hook `before` but in `ember-qunit` the only callbacks available are `beforeEach` and `afterEach`.

How can I perform that?

Comment: If i'm not wrong, no other callbacks are available. [code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/blob/master/lib/ember-qunit/qunit-module.js#L38). What do you want to do in `before` callback?

Comment: I need to init a dependency injection manager class that shouldn't be called twice

Comment: Can you do it just before the `module` function call? Such as shown in [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/860f6eea3beb86c65490ea2f29e9c36b?openFiles=tests.unit.controllers.my-controller-test.js%2C)

Comment: Here take a look at this https://github.com/flore77/qunit/commit/15775d2a1873247bd19863cf41e386e26164c881 code and this https://github.com/jquery/qunit/issues/893 issue.Hope it might help a bit

Answer (score 1):

When I wrote [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880167/how-to-call-hook-before-and-after-in-ember-qunit-tests/43355843#comment67230561_39880167) on this quesion, the repository were like this: [qunit-module.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/blob/0eebe6c868306e222706016551d1be7e7409cbb0/lib/ember-qunit/qunit-module.js#L33). So it seems there were no support for `before` and `after` hooks. So [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880167/how-to-call-hook-before-and-after-in-ember-qunit-tests/43355843#comment67306371_39880167) was initiating the manager before `module` function, shown as in [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/860f6eea3beb86c65490ea2f29e9c36b?openFiles=tests.unit.controllers.my-controller-test.js%2C).

**But,** 5 days ago, [trentmwillis](https://github.com/trentmwillis) submitted a [commit](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/pull/260/commits/06c465ebd3be5fb23debaf862cbc9154f0e2b678) and it seem master now a has the `before` and `after` hooks. I guess [ember-qunit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-qunit)'s 2.1.2 version has this commit.